# React js login with supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, supabase

I don't know why, send magic link login return
https://kkzio.github.io/#access_token=e... and make page not found
[image]

instead of https://kkzio.github.io/movie-trend/#access_token=e...
so will return https://kkzio.github.io/movie-trend/
[image]

this is my supabase site url[image]

and this my web *https://kkzio.github.io/movie-trend/* if you want to try

Answer (score 0):

When I click on the link you send, I get sent to:

https://kkzio.github.io/

I don't know if a path is supported in the Site URL, so you might need to add a default route that redirects people to your `/movie-trend` page.